# Read data from multiple pipes

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to do a model of fully connected mesh topology. I have parent and children which communicate each other using pipes. So each process have to read data from several pipes. And I don't know how to do that.

Each process has "local id" as increment (0 - parent, 1,2,3 etc).

I created 2d array of pipes. A first array - destinations, second arrays - sources:

```
struct pipes_t
{
   int rdwr[2];
};

struct dataIO_t
{
    int processes; // number of processes
    int8_t lid; // prosecc local id (0,1,2 etc)
    struct pipes_t pipes[MAX_LOCAL_ID+1][MAX_LOCAL_ID+1];
};
```

Function for sending multicast message:

```
int send(struct dataIO_t* data) {
    for(int i = 0; i < data->processes; i++)
        if(write(data->pipes[i][data->lid].rdwr[1], "Hello world\n", 12) != 1)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

How to read data from many pipes from any process without threads?
I tried to use function `dup2` for connection all pipes in one but it was bad idea:

```
int receive(struct dataIO_t* data) {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    const int BSIZE = 100;
    ssize_t nbytes;
    char buf[BSIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < data->processes; i++)
        if(i != data->lid)
            if (dup2(data->pipes[data->lid][i].rdwr[0], fd[0]) == -1)
                return 1;

    nbytes = read(fd[0], buf, BSIZE);
    printf("Msg (%d): %s\n", data->lid, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Prohibitions**: in this exercise I can't use `poll`, `select` and same functions.

Comment: The function you are looking for is `poll`; it waits on several file descriptors and returns which ones are ready to be read from or written to. There's also `select`, which is old, and `epoll`, which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I updated the question, I can't use this functions

Comment: Well, if you can't use the sensible options ([`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) and 
[`poll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) and non-standard relatives), then you'll need to make the read file descriptors non-blocking ([`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html), `F_GETFL`, `F_SETFL` and `O_NONBLOCK`), and you'll have to loop over each file descriptor to see if there's any data available to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want to read from multiple file descriptors without using poll, select, etc.

As you may have discovered, you cannot simply read from one of several pipes and hope it works, because if there is no data, you will block.

To solve this, you can set all of the file descriptors you want to read as *non-blocking*, which means a read from them will return immediately if no data is available.

In pseudo-code:

```
for each fd in fds
    mode = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, mode | O_NONBLOCK)

forever
    for each fd in fds
        if read(fd)
            process data
    sleep a little to avoid 100% CPU usage
```

Comment: Does `setsockopt()` work on pipe descriptors rather than socket descriptors?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good point, I have updated my pseudo-code to use `fcntl()` which definitely works (to the extent that pseudo-code can definitely work!).

Comment: You should be using `select` or `poll` instead of busy-waiting.